# Accessing nested models in an after_create callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a model with an `accepts_nested_attributes_for` a child model:

```
class ParentResource < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :child_resources

  accepts_nested_attributes_for :child_resources

  after_create :log_child_resources

  private
  def log_child_resources
    logger.debug "Child Resources: #{child_resources}"
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, the `after_create` callback doesn't log any child_resources, even when child_resources are provided as nested attributes. These child_resources will soon be saved and accessible, but at this point I cannot examine them `child_resources`. Presumably this is because the parent_resource is saved before its nested children, so there are not yet any children in the associative array.

So my question is: at this point in the creation cycle, is there a way to access the child_resources?

Comment: Well is the "Child Resources: " part being printed to the log? Otherwise, you may need to check whether your log output actually shows debug level messages.

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can try and log each child resource in their own after_create callbacks. Since these
records aren't created yet, you can log supplied attributes:

```
logger.debug "Child Resources: #{child_resources_attributes}"
```

Comment: Unfortunately, it looks like the getter for `child_resources_attributes` doesn't exist. I've only got the setter `child_resources_attributes=`. This seems like a good direction, at least, so long as there's a way to access the attributes.

Answer (score 0):

Alter to this,

```
  def log_child_resources
    logger.debug "Child Resources: #{self.child_resources}"
  end
```

Basically, when you create the Parent, there is no child associated with it. So, to test this. **Lets create a ChildResource and associate it with the newly created Parent** and then log it.

Which goes like as follows,

```
  def log_child_resources

    # block the creates 10 children and associates
    (1..10).each do |n|
      ChildResource.create!(name: "TestName#{n}",parent_id: self.id)
    end

    # logging 
    logger.debug "Child Resources: #{self.child_resources.map &:name}"
  end
```

**Assumed, your child_resource model name is "ChildResource", foreign key is "parent_id" and it has a "name" column.**

Comment: Yes, this works as expected. The child_resources supplied as nested attributes are still unlogged, however.

Comment: what do you mean, "child_resources supplied as nested attributes" and "unlogged"?

Comment: I'm providing child resources through `accepts_nested_attributes_for`. Those are the ones that I want to log. However, they are not being logged. Only the test resource is logged.

Comment: Can you edit your question and show me, how you are providing child resources